# Global pointer (head of linked list) not updated properly

Tags: c, list, pointers, global

I have searched a lot, before I ask this, but I can't get this small piece of code to work.
I know that using a `global pointer` (or variable) is considered a **bad practice** (instead of passing by reference) but I am forced to use this practice sadly.

What I am trying to do is to make a `linked list` which consists of nodes (`struct` with some info), and after every `insert()` the list is dynamically expanded by one `node` (unless the element in question already exists, in that case the member `name` is overwritten).

 The pointer `next` points to the next element in the `list` (that's where I assign the new node from `malloc()`.

The program **compiles correctly** and executes with the following output:
 `retrieve returned: (NULL)` at every `printf()` call

That's why I believe the global pointer (head of the list) is not updated properly

I am sorry for this naive question but I can't seem to find where the assignment/allocation goes wrong, 
Anyway thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    char *id;
    char *name;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node* list; //list head
struct node* p; //pointer to list head

char *retrieve(char *id){
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL; //list is empty, no element to return.
    for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next)
        if(strcmp(id, p->id) == 0)
            return p->name;
     return NULL;  
}

void insert(char *id, char *name){
    int exists = 0;
    struct node* temp = NULL;
    for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next){
        if(strcmp(id, p->id) == 0){ //id already exists, overwrite with the new name.
            free(p->name);
            p->name = strdup(name);
            exists = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(exists) return; 
    //insert at the end of the list
    temp = malloc(1 * sizeof(struct node));
    if(temp == NULL){
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    temp->id = strdup(id);
    temp->name = strdup(name);
    temp->next = NULL;
    p = temp;
    return;
}

int main(){
    struct node* temp = NULL;
    p = NULL;
    list = NULL;
    insert("145a","Jim");
    insert("246b","Alice");
    insert("322c","Mike");
    printf("retrieve returned: %s\n\n", retrieve("145a"));
    printf("retrieve returned: %s\n\n", retrieve("246b"));
    printf("retrieve returned: %s\n\n", retrieve("322c"));
    p = list;
    while(p != NULL){ // node deletion starting from first to last element.
        free(p->id);
        free(p->name);
        temp = p; 
        p = p->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(p = list; p != NULL; p = p->next){` after this loop, p will be NULL. The `p=temp;` afterwards will do nothing.

Comment: Using a pointer to pointer would simplify your program (and could also avoid the hard coded reference to the global variable)

Comment: @wildplasser I am quite familiar with the `pass-a-reference-to-it` part,
but I am forced to use a global hardcoded pointer (which I have minimum experience unfortunately)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void insert(char *id, char *name)
{
    struct node *temp = NULL, **pp;
      /* Pointer to pointer points to the global */    
    for(pp = &list; *pp ; pp = &(*pp)->next){
        if(strcmp(id, (*pp)->id) ) continue;

        free((*pp)->name);
        (*pp)->name = strdup(name);
        return;
        }

    //insert at the end of the list
    temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);
    if(!temp ){
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    temp->id = strdup(id);
    temp->name = strdup(name);
    temp->next = NULL;
    *pp = temp;
    return;
}
```

---

And you can even do without the *temp pointer:

```
void insert(char *id, char *name)
{
    struct node **pp;

    for(pp = &list; *pp ; pp = &(*pp)->next){
        if(strcmp(id, (*pp)->id) ) continue;
            free(p->name);
            p->name = strdup(name);
            return;
        }
    // pp now points to the terminal NULL pointer
    *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
    if(!*pp ){
        printf("memory allocation failed\n");
        return;
    }
    (*pp)->id = strdup(id);
    (*pp)->name = strdup(name);
    (*pp)->next = NULL;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `list` other than with `NULL`. In consequence,

```
char *retrieve(char *id){
    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;
```

always returns `NULL`.